# Is this patent #7,927,287 still valid and in force?

Tags: patent-infringement

Is this patent [#7,927,287](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7927287B2/en) still valid?
For me is a copy of [#6,467,430](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6467430B1/en)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the patent is still active. Google patents indicates that the expected expiration date is April 5th, 2029. This is later than 20 year from the priority date so there likely has been a patent term adjustment. I checked on the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site and there seems to be 629 days of patent term adjustments. This can occur when there are delays in processing the patent application.

As for the similarity between the patents, the earlier patent was cited in the later one so the examiner clearly knew of it. I'd review the patent's file on the US Public Pair to understand how and why US 7,927,287 was deemed patentable.

Comment: Thanks Eric. In my opinion Patent #7,927,287 "Herd Management Technology" is a patent related to the methods of use in different reproductive systems. This patent is a bluff!. What they have patented is the daily management that exists since the creation of the “Apparatus for detecting estrus in livestock”  (patent #6,467,430)

Comment: @Ezequiel  I'll take your word for it as I have no knowledge in this field. Please focus on what is in the claims. Many patents that read generally are very limited when you get to the claims.

Comment: @Ezequiel If you find the answer acceptable, please accept it by clicking in the check mark.